# Different results from deparse in R 3.4.4 and R 3.5

Tags: r

`deparse` produces different results in R 3.4.4 and R 3.5. The [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) suggests some defaults settings have changed but it is not clear to me how to ensure `deparse` produces the same output in R 3.4.4 and R 3.5

R 3.4.4

```
> deparse(list(dec = 4L, b = "a"), control = "keepNA")
[1] "list(dec = 4, b = \"a\")"
```

R 3.5

```
> deparse(list(dec = 4L, b = "a"), control = "keepNA")
[1] "list(4, \"a\")"
```

EDIT:

Thanks to helpful suggestions by @HongOoi and @akrun the closest thing to a solution that will ensure the same result in both R 3.4.4 and R 3.5 seems to be:

```
dctrl <- if (getRversion() > "3.4.4") c("keepNA", "niceNames") else "keepNA"
deparse(list(dec = 4L, b = "a"), control = dctrl)
```

Comment: You might take a look at `alist`. I'm not sure it will work for your situation, but it seems like a potential solution.

Comment: Using deparse to get the string. `alist` doesn't provide that it seems

Answer (score 4):

I haven't got R 3.5 installed, but per the NEWS file, you could try the `showAttributes` and/or `niceNames` arguments to `deparse`:

> These functions gain a new control option "niceNames" (see .deparseOpts()), which when set (as by default) also uses the (tag = value) syntax for atomic vectors. On the other hand, without deparse options "showAttributes" and "niceNames", names are no longer shown also for lists. as.character(list( c (one = 1))) now includes the name, as as.character(list(list(one = 1))) has always done.

Comment: I did see that line in NEWS but it wasn't clear to me how to actually change the settings to ensure the behavior is identical regardless of the version of R being used

Answer (score 2):

We could use `substitute` in `R 3.5` to get the same result as in `R 3.4.4`

```
deparse(substitute(list(dec = 4L, b = "a")), control = "keepNA")
#[1] "list(dec = 4, b = \"a\")"
```

Comment: This looks promising! It doesn't seem to have an effect in R 3.4.4 but does in R 3.5. It isn't clear to me *why* it works though so I'm not confident that it will have the same effect in (all) situations where I pass a list or vector of named arguments to deparse. Could you expend perhaps on why this works?

Comment: If you are really looking for only `deparse`, then as @HongOoi mentioned `deparse(list(dec = 4L, b = "a"), control = c("keepNA", "niceNames"))[1] "list(dec = 4, b = \"a\")"` should work fine.  I don't have the R 3.4.4 to check how the `substitute` behaves

Comment: @Vincent The substitute gets a language or call object which is converted to `character` with `deparse` You can check the output of `substitute(list(dec = 4L, b = "a"))`

Comment: That is useful. "niceNames" works in R 3.5 but would produce an error in R 3.4.4 (`Error: deparse option ‘niceNames’ is not recognized`)

Comment: @Vincent Proabably it is a new parameter introduced in 3.5

Comment: I understand that some of your already written codes need to be changed according to the new version.  It is a bit of headache.

Comment: It is not the change I mind so much. Just that now the code won't work on both R 3.4 *and* R 3.5. I don't want to require one or the other version for someone to use my R-package. I could add a check to see which R version is being used that seems a bit of a hack

Comment: If you already have a package, make sure that the requirement should be R 3.5 and greater, then users have to update to the new version\

Comment: @Vincent welcome to the world of breaking API changes. Stuff like this happens